# Correct the mistake

Tags: c++

Why is this code not being compiled?

```
TextMem tmem, *fp = &tmem;
char *_res = new char[textbuf.mLength + 1];

tmem.Open(textbuf, TextStream::READ | TextStream::EOL_CRLF | TextStream::EOL_ORPHAN_CR, CP_UTF8);
tmem.Read(_res, textbuf.mLength);
tmem.Close();

char dbg[256];
sprintf(dbg, "mBuffer is %X, _res is %X", textbuf.mBuffer, _res);
MessageBox(NULL, dbg, "debug", MB_OK);

for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(_res); i++)
    _res[i] ^= 168;

sprintf(dbg, "mBuffer is %X, _res is %X", textbuf.mBuffer, _res);
MessageBox(NULL, dbg, "debug", MB_OK);

textbuf.mBuffer = _res;
textbuf.mLength = _ind;

sprintf(dbg, "mBuffer is %X, _res is %X", textbuf.mBuffer, _res);
MessageBox(NULL, dbg, "debug", MB_OK);

tmem.Open(textbuf, TextStream::READ | TextStream::EOL_CRLF | TextStream::EOL_ORPHAN_CR, CP_UTF8);
```

Compiler found an error in “sprintf”, what should I do to eliminate this error?

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, always copy (as text, in full and complete) the output of the compiler and/or linker, and paste it (without modifications) into your question body. Then mark out the lines where the error(s) are in the code, with e.g. comments. Without knowing the exact error it's very hard to help you. And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: okay, thanks and sorry

Comment: `%X` could be wrong conversion specifier

Comment: @KillzoneKid `%X` is an uppercase hex value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Maybe you should replace `sprintf` with `_sprintf` because of your compiler.
I don’t see any mistakes there.

Comment: I don't think there is `_sprintf`